# Oscommerce store access from other machines using ip address

Tags: web-services, localhost, ip-address, oscommerce, static-ip-address

i created ecommerce store using oscommerce and hosted in local host on IIS. anyone can access this site **`http://27.7.136.234/oscommerce/`** but once they click on any link in the site, url changes to **`http://localhost/oscommerce/product_info.php?products_id=28`**. i.e. local host is replacing  ip address so others cant access my store. what can i do to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the URL in your config file. It should be located in the includes folder if I remember correctly.